# What is grammatical structure in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Here is the sentence:

> - 어제 연극 봤다며? 그 연극, 재미있다고 해서 나도 주말에 보러 갈까 하는데.
> - 그래? 난 별로였어. 연극 중간에 **관객을** 무대로 **나오라고 할 때가 많았**거드.

i think the subject in this sentence is "관객", so "관객을" is not correct; it must be "관객이", right? and i don't know the grammatical structure in the phrase "나오라고 할 때가 많았". Is this new grammatical structure, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

관객을 and 관객이 are both correct, though I think 관객을 is more natural here.

This is a construction that corresponds to English "ask/tell/cause (someone) to do something": here, Korean usually allows *both* subject and object markers in the position, although in some cases one of them might be more natural than the other.

Sometimes "-에게" is also allowed (e.g., "to tell (someone) to...").

> 선생님은 **철수를/철수에게** 앞으로 나오라고 했다. = The teacher told Chulsoo to come forward.
>
> 선생님은 **철수가** 앞으로 나오라고 했다. = (same, though it feels like the teacher emphasized none other than Chulsoo should come forward.)
>
> 선생님은 **철수가/철수에게** 칠판을 지우게 했다. = The teacher made Chulsoo erase the board.
>
> 선생님은 **철수를** 칠판을 지우게 했다. = (same but less natural, probably because we have two consecutive -를?)
>
> 그는 그 **프로젝트가/프로젝트를** 실패하도록 방치했다. = He abandoned the project to fail.

Back to the sentence in the question, the hidden subject is clearly 배우들 (actors).  So,

> 연극 중간에 [(배우들이) 관객을 무대로 나오라고 할] 때가 많았거든.
>
> = During the play, there were many times when [the actors asked the audience to come up to the stage].
>
> = During the play, the actors would keep asking the audience to come up to the stage.

Comment: Your explaination is very clear. Thank you so much!